# sub or function not defined : Solver not helping

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro in vba to lookup values from one sheet and return the data and save it in another sheet. But i am getting a compile error "Compile Error : Sub or function not defined".

I tried by selecting the "Solver" under references but still i am getting this error.

Here is my code ::

```
For i = 1 To j
    temp_var = config_sht_name(i)
    MsgBox temp_var

    For Each cell In Worksheets(Sheet_Name).Range("A9:A37")
        On Error Resume Next
        'Ret = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, Worksheets("config_sht_name[i]").Range("A9:E37"), 5, 0)
        Ret = VLookup(cell, Indirect(Concatenate("'", temp_var, "'!")), 5, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Ret <> "" Then
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = Ret
        End If
        MsgBox Ret

    Next
Next i
```

I am getting error for "Concatenate" and "Indirect" function.
Please suggest what am I missing.

--Sanjeev

Comment: As per error message Concatenate and Indirect are not built in VBA functions.

Comment: What value does `temp_var` hold? What do you expect `Concatenate("'", temp_var, "'!")` function to return? "Sheet1!"?

Comment: on the very top of the code editor add "OPTION EXPLICIT" (yes, outside the function, again, the 1st line of the whole code editor window should be this). Solves issues of this kind often (the directive means no variable can be used with out being declared first). The only "discomfort" is you'll have to "Dim" variables before first use

Comment: @shahkalpesh temp_var is used to store a sheet name. Concatenate will join 2 or more strings and return something like 'sheet_1'!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure with the logic of the below line

```
Ret = VLookup(cell, Indirect(Concatenate("'", temp_var, "'!")), 5, 0)
```

I suggest instead of Conconate function use

```
 str1 = "'" & temp_var & "'!"
 Ret = VLookup(cell, Range([Indirect(str1)]), 5, 0)
```